# How to put a list or map value into an embedded map using SQL update?

Tags: sql, database, orientdb

I've got a class `Item` that has a property `map` of type `EMBEDDEDMAP`.

```
INSERT INTO Item (map) VALUES ({'listin': []})
```

This INSERT creates a new record with @rid = #22:0 and map = {"listin":[0]}.
Now I want to put new entries into the `map` property using [SQL UPDATE](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/SQL-Update).

```
UPDATE #22:0 PUT map = 'strVal', 'abcdef'
```

Putting a new entry of type `String` or `Integer` into `map` works fine.
Result: map = {"listin":[0],"strVal":"abcdef"}

When I try to do the same with a list or map, I get an exception.

```
UPDATE #22:0 PUT map = 'listVal', []  
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1  

UPDATE #22:0 PUT map = 'mapVal', {}  
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
```

I followed the [OrientDB Wiki](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/SQL-Update#examples), but there are no examples for putting a collection entry into a map.
I'm using OrientDB Studio (Community Edition v1.7-rc2) to execute the queries.

**Why are these updates throwing an exception?

What is the correct way to formulate the query?**

Answer (score 2):

Try OrientDB 1.7-SNAPSHOT where we fixed this issue.

Comment: I get the same exception in OrientDB Studio with 1.7-SNAPSHOT and 2.0-SNAPSHOT.

Comment: 2.0 branch is remained un updated, are you sure you've a recent 1.7-SNAPSHOT? Can you tell me the jar signature please?